# Get username from URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, parsing

i want something like this:

```
http://www.someniceandreliableurl.com/username
```

and catch the username.

I want to make something like twitters/facebook/etc quick urls...

```
twitter.com/username
```

How can i make something like this with php? =) thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure but you might be able to just use a file by that name in the directory, and have #!\locationToPHPhere at the top of the file assuming you are using linux for your environment.  This may cause the shell to treat it as a php file at which point you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @Josh - that would tend to fail if you had any decent sized userbase

Comment: All three answers presume you're running PHP under Apache. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, it is apache+linux, thanks for your answers. :) i will try RewriteRules :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **mod_rewrite** in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Where *foo.php* is your script for showing the quick url pages.

Then in *foo.php* (or whatever you named it) you can catch the username in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

The first 5 lines turn on **mod_rewrite** and allow actual files/folders/scripts to be ignored by the rewrite rule. The last one rewrites all the urls that aren't fines/folders/scripts.

Comment: Thanks, just to add:

Mod Rewrite, should be ON (LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so, on httpd.conf)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a RewriteRule in apache to transform a site.com/user to be site.com/loadpage.php?user=user

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9]+)  /load_user.php?user=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, im having trouble testing this (i have to wait) but it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the webserver to rewrite that url to a query string with data that you can access from PHP. Do your PHP script to work with urls like

```
http://www.someniceandreliableurl.com/?user=username
```

Then ensure that apache have mod_rewrite installed and that you are allowed to use .htaccess. Then create a .htaccess file with a rewrite rule, like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$ /?user=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: @Joshua: Not a reason to downvote, IMO. The answer is naturally going to be at the bottom of the list anyway, because the other two answers were here first and thus got a head start. It's still a valid answer; no need to punish @Johan for being a slower typist.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout ModRewrite in Apache or use a php framework that offers routing. This is generally based on the `$ENV['PHP_SELF']` variable which lets you do much more in your php code that you would normally have to do in ModRewrite. It will return the part of the url after the hostname so you can do urls like http://exmaple.com/index.php/username/profile.