# Add 'username' to URL from 'user_id' with PHP for Dummies

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to publish a question which I know has many answers floating around Stack Overflow.  However I, for some reason, just cannot seem to get the information in them to click. I will post my sources at the end of the question.

The question being, how can I pull a `user_id` from a URL & mod_rewrite it show the username.

Instead of this:

`domain/user/index.php?user_id=1`

I get this:

`domain/username`

I had customized other SO answers to my needs on my .htaccess file to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
  RewriteRule .* - [L]
  RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ index.php?user_id=$1
</IfModule>
```

The `if` statement at the top of my user page looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['user_id']) || isset($_GET['username']) && queryUserId($user_id)) {
  // Render Page Content
} else {
  header('Location: sign_up.php');
}
```

And my `queryUsername` functions looks like this:

```
function queryUsername($username) {
    $conn = dbConnect('read');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$username."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row['username'];
    $username = $row['username'];
}
```

I have successfully implemented unique URL's for users, and am accessing Account Profiles just fine when appending different user_id's to my URL, so what am I missing to get the username written to the URL instead of variable strings and folder structure?

Cheers!

Other SO Questions:

[Directly adding username to URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819284/directly-adding-username-to-url-php)

[Get username from URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784214/get-username-from-url-in-php)

[Using mod rewrite to change URL with username variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904075/using-mod-rewrite-to-change-url-with-username-variable)

AddedBytes Article

[URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong according to your information:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ index.php?user_id=$1
```

It should at least be:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ /user/index.php?user_id=$1    // for a url like domain/user/username
```

or using your description:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /user/index.php?user_id=$1    // for a url like domain/username
```

Also, you are not setting any variable with the name of `username` in the code you have shown, so the check for `$_GET['username']` is unnecessary.

Your check in php should look something like:

```
if ( isset($_GET['user_id']) && queryUserId($_GET['user_id']) ) {
```

Apart from that you should not use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and use prepared statements as you have an sql injection problem now.

Also note that using two `return` statements after each other only returns the first value.

**Edit:** There seems to be some confusion between the user ID and the username. If the value in the url is a username, you'd better call it `username` in both the .htaccess file and php to avoid confusion with the user ID:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /user/index.php?username=$1    // for a url like domain/username}
```

and

```
if ( isset($_GET['username']) && queryUserName($_GET['username']) ) {
```

in the function (**using the deprecated functions just to illustrate**...):

```
function queryUserName($username) {        
    $conn = dbConnect('read');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Let me implement your suggestions, I will post back.

Comment: Alright, I have modified much of my code, and I am close.  I am receiving a page when I go to `domain.com/username` which is just great.  I am however not pulling in any data to that page, so I need to restructure my variables.  Thank you so much for the outstanding and educational answer. +1 & answer.